# Stacked data under X axis on JavaFX LineChart

Tags: javafx, linechart

Im creating a program that is putting certain data on javafx linechart. I added one combobox with 3 items in it. Here is a fragment of my code adding items to combobox:

```
 void setComboBox() {
            comboBox.getItems().addAll("a", "b", "c");
        }
```

In order for combo box to function properly i added actionlistener:

```
 public void setItem1(ActionEvent a) {


    String itemType = (String) comboBox.getValue();


    if (itemType == "a") {
        readData(loadJson.getPrices(), loadJson.getDate());
        System.out.println("a");
    }
    if (itemType == "b") {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
    if (itemType == "c") {
        System.out.println("c");
    }


}
```

The "loadJson" object is an object of a class that is reading data from a JSON file, i want to print the chart only after clicking on a certain item from my combobox. Unfortunately, when i do it this way, the data under X axis seems to be mashed/stacked. Here is a screenshot on how it looks: [image]

What can i do to repair it? Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I believe one workaround is to turn the chart's animation off (e.g. `chart.setAnimated(false)`).

Comment: Though I think the real fix, assuming the x-axis is a `CategoryAxis`, is to add the categories to the axis as well, not just the chart's data.

Comment: @Slaw what do you mean "add the categories to the axis"? I dont think i understand. I have the line chart object, category axis object and number axis object defined in my Controller class. But im not sure, how do i add it this way, rather than just via XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series(); and lineChart.getData().addAll(series);

Comment: See [`CategoryAxis#getCategories()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html#getCategories()). The idea is that the axis should have each _possible_ category any of the `Data` can be "in".

Comment: Ok, thank you. How can i implement it, and where? In the method where i draw the chart or somewhere else?

Comment: Depends on if the categories are known ahead-of-time or are determined on-demand. If the former, add the categories when you create the entire `LineChart`. If the latter, set the categories when you add the data.